# How can I resolve this Error - " ValueError: Negative values in data passed to MultinomialNB (input X)

Tags: python, machine-learning, multinomial

```
model_3 = MultinomialNB()
model_3.fit(X_train,np.ravel(y_train))
y_predict = model_3.predict(X_test)
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_predict)
print(accuracy)
```

I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: Negative values in data passed to MultinomialNB (input X)
```

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: You are giving model_3 a negative number, which is not allowed.

Comment: Would help if you could check (eg by printing) what value you are passing to MultinomialNB.

Comment: Does my answer solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `MinMaxScaler()` to preprocess the data before sending the data to the model. This normalizes it to the range `0 to 1` thus removing the negative numbers.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler #fixed import

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```